# What is the physical meaning of the higher order structure functions in the BRST quantization of open algebras?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

What is the physical meaning of the higher order structure functions in the BRST quantization of open algebras? As opposed to formal algebraic manipulations.

Thanks.

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38623/2451) post.