# How does the BRST transformation act on ghost fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, brst, ghosts

I understand the general idea behind constructing the BRST symmetry: take a generic gauge transformation

$$\begin{equation}
e^\omega,
\end{equation}\tag{1}$$

where $\omega$ is Lie-algebra valued, and replace $\omega$ with some Grassmann number $\epsilon$ times the ghost field $c$:

$$\begin{equation}
e^\omega\rightarrow e^{\epsilon c}.
\end{equation}\tag{2}$$

Of course this doesn't tell you how the ghosts or Nakanishi-Lautrup fields ($B$) change. I've seen an additional term added, which is something like:

$$\begin{equation}
\omega\rightarrow \epsilon c + \epsilon~\text{Tr}(c^2b),
\end{equation}\tag{3}$$

but I can't quite work out how this term comes into play. I assume that: one, the extra term is fine because it goes as a BRST variation of the ghosts $\delta c\sim c^2$ and must be exact, and two, that the extra term somehow imposes conditions on the transformations for the antighost ($b$) and $B$ fields. I could try brute-forcing this calculation, but I can't really figure out how the Slavnov operator (or really gauge transformations in general) act on ghosts, antighosts or auxiliary fields. Specifically, gauge transformations act by conjugation (+ a derivative) on gauge bosons, since they are in the adjoint representation. Of course, so are $c$, $b$, and $B$, but acting naively on $c$ like $$c\rightarrow c'=g(c-Dg)g^{-1}\tag{4}$$ seems to only produce nonsense. Can someone help clarify this behavior?

Comment: Eq. (3) above can be found, for example, in Green-Schwarz-Witten (p. 132, eq. 3.2.4) or here https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/BRST/Notes.pdf (p. 32).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The BRST transformation rules for the ghost fields follow from requiring that the BRST/Slavnov operator squares to zero (= is nilpotent in physics jargon).

More details: When studying the BRST formalism, one should be aware that there exists$^1$ at least 2 versions relevant to OP's question:

1. *The Hamiltonian Batalin–Fradkin–Vilkovisky (BFV) formalism.* Assuming no second-class constraints, and that the [first-class constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint) $G_a(q,p)$ are irreducible,

   - the minimal field multiplet is the original position variables $q^i$ and the Faddeev-Popov (FP) ghost ${\cal C}^a$,
   - while the non-minimal field multiplet is the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda^a$ and the FP antighost $\bar{\cal C}_a$.

   On top of that there are the corresponding momenta, namely $p_i$, the FP ghost momenta $\bar{\cal P}_a$; the Nakanishi-Lautrup (NL) field $B_a$, and the FP antighost momenta ${\cal P}^a$, respectively.

   As usual, the above canonical pairs of operators can be realized via a suitable Schrödinger representation.

   Note that the bar/overline in $\bar{\cal C}_a$ and $\bar{\cal P}_a$ does *not* denote complex nor Hermitian conjugation. Rather, it signifies a negative ghost number.

   Also note that that the FP ghost ${\cal C}^a$ and antighost $\bar{\cal C}_a$ are *not* a canonical pair, i.e. they super-commute.

   The BRST charge operator
   $$\begin{align} Q~=~&Q_{\min} + Q_{\text{non-min}},\cr
   Q_{\min}~=~&G_a {\cal C}^a +\frac{1}{2}\bar{\cal P}_cf^c{}_{ab}{\cal C}^b{\cal C}^a +\ldots, \cr
   Q_{\text{non-min}}~=~&B_a{\cal P}^a, \end{align}$$
   is (among other things) a Grassmann-odd operator of ghost number +1 that squares to zero
   $$ Q^2~=~0,$$
   cf. Ref. 1. The above ellipses $\ldots$ refers to higher-order terms, where each term contains one more ghost ${\cal C}^a$ than ghost momenta $\bar{\cal P}_a$. Such term may be needed if the structure functions $f^c{}_{ab}(q,p)$ are not constant.

   See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38623/2451) related Phys.SE post.

   The BRST transformations $$\delta~=~[Q,\cdot]$$ are given by the super-commutator. So e.g. the ghost transforms as
   $$\delta {\cal C}^c~=~[Q,{\cal C}^c]~=~\frac{1}{2}f^c{}_{ab}{\cal C}^b{\cal C}^a+\ldots,$$
   cf. OP's title question.
2. The same formalism where half of the variables (mostly momenta) have been integrated out. The remaining variables are the original position variables $q^i$, the FP ghost ${\cal C}^a$, the FP antighost $\bar{\cal C}_a$, and the NL auxiliary field $B_a$. This is the version usually found in textbooks.

   The field $b$ found in the string theory literature is either the antighost $\bar{\cal C}$ or the ghost momentum $\bar{\cal P}$, depending on context.

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994; Chapter 9.

--

$^1$ There is also a Lagrangian [BV formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism).

Comment: How does the ghost momentum relate to the antighosts? Is it just the momentum conjugate? Green-Schwarz-Witten outright calls them antighosts.

Comment: But what $\textit{is}$ the ghost momentum? And how should one impose a standard gauge transformation on ghosts? I would imagine it should have a similar rule to the gauge bosons, because they are in the adjoint representation, but I can't just add a covariant derivative, because that transforms as a vector. Is it reasonable to look for an expression like $c\rightarrow c+\delta c$ under a gauge transformation?

Comment: I'm led to belive that it's just the momentum conjugate. The explicit representation of the slavnov operator given in Weinberg Vol. II contains a term
$-\frac{1}{2}{f^a}_{bc}c^bc^c\frac{\delta}{\delta c^a}.$ That derivative on the end looks awfully similar to the definition of the canonical momentum conjugate, and since it takes the form of a tangent vector, I imagine it corresponds to an antighost, so that ghosts (one forms) and antighosts are dual. Am I totally off-base here?

Comment: Page 39, eq. 15.8.9:
$$
s=\omega^A\delta_A\phi^r\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\phi^r}-\frac{1}{2}\omega^B\omega^C{f^A}_{BC}\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\omega^A}-h^A\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\omega^{*A}},
$$
where the indices represent spacetime, Lorentz, color, etc. indices collectively.

Comment: I just realized I said "canonical momentum conjugate." I don't know what that means... I meant "momentum conjugate"

Comment: I updated the answer.